# Visual Studio keeps adding resource.h in the project of a satellite DLL

Tags: visual-studio, resources, project-settings

My C++/CLI application (previously created with VS2008) is in English and has a separate resource DLL for the French version.  Both are sharing the same resource.h file

```
...\MyApp\resource.h
...\MyApp\MyApp.rc (English resources)
...\MyApp\MyAppFR\MyAppFR.rc (French resources)
```

Although MyAppFR.rc does `#include "resource.h"`, it has none in its folder.  Instead, I told the compiler to add the base project's folder in its "Additional Include Directories".  It works fine and I had no issue with VS2008.

Now, the project has been converted to VS2012.  Everytime a change is made in the French resource, the project file is checked-out and "resource.h" is added to it.  I've tried to exclude the file from the build and also from the project, but the file is still added.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the resource.h file in the Solution Explorer
2. File->Source Control->Advanced->Exclude resource.h from Source Control

This will checkout project files.  Check them in.

The resource.h file will still be visible in the project but will also have a little red dot next to its name indicating that it will be ignored by the source controller.